# Restarting a canvas animation using OOP method

Tags: javascript, oop, animation, canvas, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a webpage where each key you press on the keyboard generates a new sound/animation. I'm only on my first key at the moment but I'm having a problem where after the first key is pressed, the animation just gets stuck. Instead of starting the animation over again or starting a new animation depending on which key is pressed, the rectangle(in this case) will just start flickering. Below is some of my code.

```
class Drawable{
constructor(context, x = 0, y = 0, fillStyle = "#000", strokeStyle = "transparent", lineWidth = 0){
this.context = context;
if(!(this.context instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D)){
  throw new Error("You must provide a valid canvas context to Drawables.");
}
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.fillStyle = fillStyle;
this.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
this.deltas = new Map();

this.limits = {
    max: new Map(),
    min: new Map()
};
}
draw(){
   this.context.save();
   this.context.translate(this.x, this.y);
   this.context.scale(2,1.5);
   this.context.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;
   this.context.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle;
   this.context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
}
afterDraw(){
   this.context.restore();
}
 applyAnimation(secondsElapsed){
  for(const[propertyName, valueChangePerSecond] of this.deltas){
      const changedAmount = secondsElapsed * valueChangePerSecond;
      this[propertyName] += changedAmount;
      if(this.limits.max.has(propertyName)){
          this[propertyName] =     Math.min(this[propertyName],this.limits.max.get(propertyName));
      } else if(this.limits.min.has(propertyName)){
          this[propertyName] = Math.max(this[propertyName],this.limits.min.get(propertyName));
      }
   }  
   }
 }
  class Rectangle extends Drawable{  
constructor(context, x = 0, y = 0, fillStyle = "#000", strokeStyle = "transparent", lineWidth = 0, deltas = new Map(), width = 100, height = 100){
super(context, x, y, fillStyle, strokeStyle, lineWidth, deltas);
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
}

draw(){
super.draw();
this.context.fillRect( this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
this.context.strokeRect( this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
super.afterDraw();
}
loopDraw(){
    super.draw();
    let rectSize = 30;
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        let yPos = (rectSize - 10)*i;
        for(let j = 0; j < 6; j++){
              this.context.fillRect((rectSize+10)*j,yPos,this.width/-2,this.height/-2);
            this.context.strokeRect(this.width / -2, this.height / -2, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    super.afterDraw();
}
}
const canvas = document.getElementById("soundBoardCanvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const animationAObjects = new Set();
 // Creating the rectangle and setting the animation properties of the rectangle
let animationARect = new Rectangle(context,canvas.width/1.5,canvas.height/2, randomColour(), "transparent", 0, new Map() ,50,50);

animationARect.deltas.set("y",100);
animationARect.deltas.set("height",50);
animationARect.deltas.set("width",50);
animationARect.deltas.set("x",100);
animationARect.limits.max.set("y", canvas.height/2);
animationARect.limits.max.set("x", canvas.width/2.5);
animationARect.limits.max.set("height",randomBetween(100,170));
animationARect.limits.max.set("width",randomBetween(100,170));

animationAObjects.add(animationARect);


function randomBetween(min,max){
let range = max - min;

let random = Math.random();
random = random * (range + 1);
random = random + min;

return random;
}

// Animates all of the objects in the selected set
function animationA(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animationA);
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    const diffSeconds = (Date.now() - lastTime) / 1000;
    lastTime = Date.now();

    if(diffSeconds > 0){
        for(const animationAObject of animationAObjects){
            animationAObject.applyAnimation(diffSeconds);
            animationAObject.draw();
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
if(e.keyCode == 65){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animationA);
}
});
```

Comment: There is missing code. From what you have give there is no reason for the problem you describe. BTW requestAnimationFrame passes as the first argument to the callback a high resolution time 1/1,000,000th sec in ms (1/1000th) the smallest value 0.001ms. `function animationA(time){`

Comment: @Blindman67 I have now added all of the code to the edit above. Hopefully that should explain it better. Can you elaborate on the comment you made about requestAnimationFrame, I don't quite follow you.

Comment: When the browser calls the "callback" function you pass to `requestAnimationFrame` the first argument passed to the callback is time. eg `function callback(time){ // time argument passed by RAF`    `requestAnimationFrame(callback); // set the RAF callback function`

Answer (score 1):

You are never creating the `requestId` (or even declare it anywhere), so that should throw an error (in strict mode at least). And then you're just creating a new animation every time <kbd>a</kbd> is pressed, which may interfere with each other and cause the flickering (though I can't tell why exactly).

```
let requestId = 0; // declare this!
let lastTime = Date.now(); // important initialisation

function animationA(){
    requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationA);
//  ^^^^^^^^
    …
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
    if (e.keyCode == 65) {
        requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animationA);
//      ^^^^^^^^^
    }
});
```

Comment: I have just made these changes to my code and it has made no difference still. When I repeat a key press the shapes are not redrawn and the animation is not repeated. Instead the shapes just sit there static.

Comment: @seanrs97 Are you getting any errors? Have you debugged animation? Is `animationA` called regularly? Does `applyAnimation` do what you want? Why is `loopDraw` never called anywhere? Add some logs to see what happens with your objects, not only what happens on the canvas.

Comment: I have checked for errors, none at all. LoopDraw is a separate draw method that isn't needed as of yet. It won't be affecting the code. Apply animation is doing what I want to my knowledge. I will put in a few console.logs to see if this helps at all.